# SQL to find candidates who passed all events

Tags: sql

I have a SQL question that I have not been able to construct the query for: I have 3 tables, one lists candidates (indexed by c_id), one for events (indexed by event_id, FK c_id and has columns for event_type and one for raw_score) and another score "lookup" table (has columns for event_type, raw_score and scaled_score).

The question I am really trying to answer is find me all the candidates who passed all 4 of the different event types (one being binary the rest need a score of 70).

The solution that I came up with involves one CTE that uses a having clause, and a second that groups by id's within that table, counts the rows in each group and only returns the one where the count is at least 3. The issue with this is is that it does not explicitly check for the 3 different events, just that the count is at least 3, but the candidate could have a row for 3 of the same event types. What should I do?

```sql
WITH candidates (brandi_id) AS (
    SELECT e.brandi_id
    FROM event AS e
    LEFT JOIN apf_score_lookup AS ss
        ON ss.asmnt_code = e.asmnt_code
        AND ss.raw_score = e.score
    GROUP BY e.brandi_id, e.asmnt_code, ss.scaled_score
    HAVING e.asmnt_code IN ('APFPS','APFSU','APF2M')
    AND ss.scaled_score >= 70
)
SELECT candidates.brandi_id
FROM  candidates
LEFT JOIN event AS e
    ON e.brandi_id = candidates.brandi_id
WHERE e.asmnt_code = 'APFPL'
    AND e.score > 0
GROUP BY candidates.brandi_id
HAVING count(candidates.brandi_id) >= 3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select sl.brandi_id
from apf_score_lookup sl join
     event e
     on ss.asmnt_code = e.asmnt_code and
        ss.raw_score = e.score
where e.asmnt_code IN ('APFPS', 'APFSU', 'APF2M') and
      ss.scaled_score >= 70
group by sl.brandi_id
having count(distinct e.asmnt_code) = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had to modify it a little, but that does the trick.